# Throttle CPU NODE.JS action to allow new calls to be processed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, fork

I have an expressJS application that accepts a request that results in 1K to 50K fs.link() actions being executed. (it might even hit 500K).

The request (a POST) is not being held up while this occurs. I immediately fire of a res.send() which makes the client happy.

But the server then "forks" the job below, which needs to go and do all the fs.links() which do happen async, but the amount of work (CPU, DISK etc.) means that the ExpressJS service is not very responsive to new requests during this time.

Is there some easy way (other than childProcess) to simulate the forking of a low priority thread that would be doing these file linking?

---

```
Job.prototype.runJob = function (next) {
    var self = this;
    var max = this.files.length;
    var count = 0;
    async.each(this.files,
        function (file, step) {
            var src = path.join(self.sourcePath, file.path);
            var base = path.basename(src);
            var dest = path.join(self.root, base);
            fs.link(src, dest, function (err) {
                if (err) {
//                    logger.addLog('warn', "fs.link failed for file: %s", err.message, { file: src });
                    self.filesMissingList.push(src);
                    self.errors = true;
                    self.filesMissing++;
                } else {
                    self.filesFound++;
                }
                self.batch.update({ tilesCount: ++count, tilesMax: max, done: false });
                step(null);
            });
        },
        function (err) {
            self.batch.update({ tilesCount: count, tilesMax: max, done: true });
            next(null, "FalconView Linking of: " + self.type + " run completed");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`webworker-threads`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads) module, which is good for spinning CPU-intensive tasks onto other threads. Alternatively, you could abuse `cluster`, but it's really the wrong tool for the job. (The `cluster` module is really better for scaling up web services, not for doing intensive tasks.)

Comment: I added a code sample of the linking task. (a) I am not sure if this is a CPU bound problem or I/O (linking files seems to be more an I/O issue theoretically). the workther-threads would be interesting, but they say you need a working node-gyp, and I have been unable to get that working for months (issue is still open). What about something simple. E.g. every 1,000 files, call a timeout routine that sleeps that node "thread" and then resumes the linking process later.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you might be abusing `async.each` by calling it on every file. (`async.eachLimit` might help, but you'll still be generating tons of events.) This is making your task more CPU-intensive than it needs to be. I suggest you profile to discover exactly how much overhead there is to calling `fs.link` with async rather than all at once, and then try something like splitting your files array into 1000-file chunks. You should be able to avoid the event spam (since 500K files will only produce 500 events anyway) and still let other events run in between.

Comment: I will try async.eachLimit() to see if it helps. All I really want to do is the equiv of a thread.yield() so that a new ExpressJS request (a poll for progress) can be handled. If this means that the original request is forced to stall, or throttled to 50% that would be fine. Just how to do I force the "thread" to stall. I.e could I insert at process.nextTick() into the .each loop, would it help? and how to put it in?

Comment: There's no way to "yield the thread" like that. Functions always execute to completion synchronously. Instead, you need to break up your larger task into smaller units of work. That's what you were doing before, but you were breaking it into hundreds of thousands of tasks, which was probably overloading your event loop (and the task creation itself was computationally expensive). Try creating a smaller number of tasks that each do more work, and tune the numbers until you get the desired performance.

Comment: Henry, perhaps I am not explaining myself. But I looked at this article: http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick, and to me it basically says that process.nextTick() is the classic C.S. technique of saying "yield" this thread. It pauses current "thread" execution (albeit after the current call stack finishes), places call back on the event queue, and lets all the other waiting "threads" execute. Which seems one way to handle this. I will report back.

Comment: using async.eachLimit(files, 10, ...) was sufficient. That causes an i/o stall, and allows the other http requests to be handled. Thank you.

Comment: You can call `process.nextTick()` and hand it another chunk of work to do, yes. What I mean is that you cannot call it in the middle of a function and expect the remainder of the function to execute later. It's the provided callback which executes later. The current execution context does not yield (that word has a different meaning in other environments, which may be the source of confusion here) but rather finishes. Calling `nextTick()` is just saying "here's a function, I want you to run it later."

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Use async.eachLimit instead of async.each. This way you can control how many iterations you process before an expressJS process.